# Looping the data from WordPress database using foreach

Tags: plugins, php, sql

I am trying to fetch data from the WordPress database table using `wpdb` and loop it using foreach statement so as to output results in `select tag`. I created a custom WordPress template and this was to enable me to utilize the `wpdb` function. This query `$worktype =$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM cww_avid_worktype;", OBJECT );`  works fine when dump using `print_r($worktype );`, its return array results from the table hence means connection to the database is ok.

And the statement below works fine in pure PHP.

**ISSUE**
When I loop `$worktype` using foreach it does not output any results or any error and I have turned on debug in wp-config.
**Foreach Loop**

```
<select name="worktype" id="worktype" class="form-control required" >
<?php
global $wpdb;
$worktype =$wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM cww_avid_worktype;", OBJECT );
foreach ($worktype as $val) {
if ($val->idworkType == $post['worktype']) {
echo '<option selected="selected" id="' . $val->idworkType . 'wt" value="' . $val->idworkType . '" title="' . $val->amount_added . '">' . $val->name . '</option>';
}
else {
echo '<option id="' . $val->idworkType . 'wt" value="' . $val->idworkType . '" title="' . $val->amount_added . '">' . $val->name . '</option>';
}
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure it out, I didn't call the method on instance correctly, inside the if statement `if ($val->idworkType == $post['worktype'])`. I used this `$post['worktype']` instead of this `$post->worktype`.